# Image become gone when the view is reloaded in adapter

Tags: android

I have a image button and a image view. I am trying to get a hover theme,like when the user clicks an item there will be a hover image over the item which means he checked the item. My xml:

## layout1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    

    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/fetchedImageObj"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/test"
        android:background="@drawable/image_selector"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:padding="0dp"
        />
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/hoverImage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/correct"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my adapter where i am trying to do the task. But the problem whenerver i select a item and scrolls down it disappears or switch to other object

## Adapter:

```
public class FetchItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity myContext;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public FetchModel fetchModel;
    private boolean check_click=false;
    
    public FetchItemAdapter(Activity context,FetchModel fetchModel)
    {
        this.myContext=context;
        inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        this.fetchModel = fetchModel;
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.fetchModel.images.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
private static class ViewHolder {
        
      
        ImageButton fetchedImageObj;
        ImageView selection;
  
}
    
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("get View");
        
        
        
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        
        
        convertView = inflater.inflate(com.yolove.R.layout.fetched_images_row,null);
        
        //viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.fetchedImageObj = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(com.yolove.R.id.fetchedImageObj);
        viewHolder.selection=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(com.yolove.R.id.hoverImage);
        
        
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        
        
       ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(fetchModel.images.get(position).imageurl,viewHolder.fetchedImageObj);
            
     
       viewHolder.fetchedImageObj.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(check_click==false)
                {
                    viewHolder.selection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    check_click=true;
                    
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    viewHolder.selection.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    check_click=false;
                }
                    
            }
        });
       
            return convertView;
    }

}
```

I have made my holder final to get the viewholder.selection object.

Comment: You should use view holder pattern in get view

Answer (score 1):

On my opinion you need to make a selector xml for your image background and set the image view visible in xml file.

Comment: how to make view visible in selector xml

Comment: you need to make a selector xml in drawable folder like

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/accdetailtable" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/accdetailtable" android:state_selected="false"/>
</selector>